# Link component update browser history when location is the same

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I used react router v **4.3.1**
When i click on home page link many times, each click creates a new history item. Home page is re-rendered every time. Now your browser navigation is broken (back/forward buttons are not working as expected).

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const Example = () => (
  <Router>
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li><Link to="/">Home</Link></li> 
        <li><Link to="/">Home 1</Link></li>
        <li><Link to="/">Home 2</Link></li>
        <li><Link to="/about">About</Link></li>
        <li><Link to="/topics">Topics</Link></li>
      </ul>

      <hr />

      <Route exact path="/" render={()=><p>Home</p>} />
      <Route path="/about" render={()=><p>about</p>} />
      <Route path="/topics" render={()=><p>topics</p>} />
    </div>
  </Router>
);

render(<Example />, document.body);
```

Help, how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

It's an old and known issue introduced with React Router v4 and it's currently (AFAIK) unsolved.

Fortunately it's pretty easy to workaround using a custom history object (something you would do also if you want to keep in sync Redux state with the browser history). True production code should be more robust than what I'm writing here but you can start with this:

a) First of all use `<Router>` instead of `<BrowserRouter>`.

```
import { Router, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
```

b) Creates your own history object (be sure to `npm add history` if you didn't):

```
import createBrowserHistoryfrom "history/createBrowserHistory";

// ...

const history = createBrowserHistory();
```

c) Replace the `push()` method with your own implementation:

```
const originalHistoryPush = history.push;

history.push = function(path, state = {}) {
    if (!this.location) {
        originalHistoryPush(path, state);
        return;
    }

    const oldPath = this.location.pathname + this.location.search + this.location.hash;
    if (oldPath !== path || !shallowEqual(state, this.location.state)) {
        originalHistoryPush(path, state);
    } else {
        this.replace(path, state);
    }
};
```

d) Use the *custom* history:

```
<Router history={history}>...</Router>
```

---

Note that I'm using an hypothetical `shallowEqual()` method for comparison. You can quickly write your own or pick one of the many implementations out there.

Comment: your answer good, but it's like "monkey patching", i thinking about this too, but it's not really solution

Comment: You're right, it's a workaround until React Router guys decide what to do about this (I didn't check later but if you still have this issue in 4.3.1 then it's probably still unsolved) but there isn't really anything else than a workaround until they fix this directly in `<Link>` and `<NavLink>`.

Comment: what exactly must do "oldHistoryPush" ?

Comment: Just typo, it's `originalHistoryPush` (the _default_ implementation for `history.push()`.)

Answer (score -2):

This should solve your problem, tell me if not.

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const Home = () => <p>Home</p>;
const About = () => <p>about</p>;
const Topics = () => <p>topics</p>;

const Example = () => (
  <Router>
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li><Link to="/">Home</Link></li> 
        <li><Link to="/">Home 1</Link></li>
        <li><Link to="/">Home 2</Link></li>
        <li><Link to="/about">About</Link></li>
        <li><Link to="/topics">Topics</Link></li>
      </ul>

      <hr />

      <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
      <Route path="/about" component={About} />
      <Route path="/topics" component={Topics} />
    </div>
  </Router>
);

render(<Example />, document.body);
```

Comment: you just change render to component, it's useless